# HTML5: "local storage" and "sqlite storage" Limits

Tags: html, storage

I have seen posted limits on client-side storage:
LocalStorage: sizes are 5MB
Sqlite storage: 5MB expandable by user request.

First, are these numbers still correct?  ...and how about "sessions storage" too?

Secondly, are these storage schemes mutually exclusive? ... or is this limit an aggregate of all client-side storage - LocalStorage, SessionStorage, Cache (via manifest) and Sqlite data.

Thanks for your help.

Greg

Comment: What are you expecting to be storing on the client?

Comment: At this particular moment, not much.

Comment: At this particular moment, not much.

In general, base64 images, javascript files and css files that are common among applications.  Also, within applications, common "page fragments."

Currently I can save and reuse these files in local storage and/or sqlite. However, I look at the sqlite storage as more for application specific persistent data for user consumption - selection, change and addition.  Note, lists, todo applications come to mind here.

So I am seeking information as to "best utilization practices" for data segregation by type/use and limits - individual and totals.

Comment: It is a good idea to not store all of your client's data on the client-side. The general purpose of this is to allow for offline storage, so a backup copy may be used should the client go offline. Additionally, this reduces the web application to a regular application since users would be dependent on using the same computer and the same web browser rather than allowing the use of multiple computers.

Comment: @Maz,  Yes.  I totally agree from a data storage position.  But I also think that a multi-application toolset benefits from common support files so cached and maintained as a background application task.  - greg

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge that 5mb shared across local storage,session storage.If we close the browser session storage keys are removed as data saved per session.
And this 5mb is per domain.
i.e., browser will allocate 5mb for abc.com ,5mb for xyz.com. etc..
And abc.com cannot access xyz.com local storage elements.

Answer (score -1):

There is three type of Storage available in HTML5

1. LocalStorage
2. SessionStorage
3. WebSQL Storage

LocalStorage :- used for save data at client side.it is like cookies but it wont sent to every HTTP request.

SessionStorage :- used for save data for a session.

WEBSQLStorage :- used for save data in databases. by default limit is 5MB.but it's size is vary accross the browsers

Comment: This is a textbook answer and doesn't answer the question.